# Firebase security and phone authentication

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm a new android developer and so confused about firebase rules and phone authentication.
I am writing an application for a scheduling system.
Right now, I'm using a phone number to authenticate users.
In my plan, I want to save the appointments in my realtime database firebase, and for each phone number I want to add user information, like name and their appointments.
The first question is how can I create a user for each phone? can I do that with phone authentication or do I need to create a user object and save it in the realtime database?
The second question is about security. I want my users to be able to see all the free appointments and to schedule one or more. What rules do I need to set for each user?

Comment: My users as in even the one who not authenticate themselves or are all of them having authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Firebase Authentication via phone number as [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth). Once a user authenticates himself then a unique Uid is created for that person which you can use to get the User data using `auth` variable. This is using `Firebaseuser` as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users)

If you want to make custom made fields for a user I would advise to get the Uid  and then create a user databse in lets say `/Users` using the Uid as the primary key, that would be something like `/Users/Uid`

Further if you want your authenticated users only to see the free appointments you can do something like below, assuming the Appointment branch in root contains the available free slots.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Appointments": {
      "freeSlots": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can then manipulate the database via your codes, probably shift the free slot from Appointment to the `/User/Uid`

Then if you wish the user to see his slots only, you can write the rules like below

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here the `$uid` ensures that the user only reads the data belonging to them.

You can find further help with security rules [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

Hope this could help you a bit?

Comment: That's amazing! tnx a lot.
I have one more question for now:
If a user tries to log in before he signed up, how can I check if this user is authenticated or not, according to his phone number?

Comment: Thank you ersa. If you think the answer helped you, can you mark it as accepted. Also give me a moment to get back to you with your query. I hope you are doing some research and googling before asking?

Comment: yes, of course. I found this but I can't understand what I have to import:
UserRecord userRecord = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);

Comment: You can see what all data the UserRecord class has from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord). As you can see you can fetch the uid from the userRecord variable

Comment: but I can't find getUserByPhoneNumber function under  FirebaseAuth.getInstance, I don't know why.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220367/discussion-between-shubham-rohila-and-ersa).

Answer (score 0):

1. you already implemented Firebase phone Auth, the next step is to create a document for each user to store the information you want by making use of unique uid String that comes with each user's authentication.
2. to add security of who reads/writes what you have to write database rules [Info here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started)